# How to obtain android activity lifecycle events from view?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm creating a component that is intended to be used in some other application who's Activity I have no control over.  In my View based component I'm wanting to know when the parent activity is going away (onPause) and coming back (onResume).  I found that the Application class allows registration of a callback for these events in API 14 but I'm stuck coding to API 8.

I've tried various ViewTreeObserver attempts but they seem flaky and doesn't seem like a proper fit.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your custom view with methods for each lifecycle event, like onActivityPause, onActivityResume etc.
Have the activity that uses your view 'forward' its life cycle events to these methods.

This is how Google does it with the new v2 MapView.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the options I considered but in this case I'm stuck.  I have to code to an API that needs to know when my component spins up a browser intent (or something else causing the parent activity to onPause).  That one is easy as I can make a safe assumption that starting another intent will wipe out the parent Activity.  However, going the other direction almost seems impossible without forwarding or the new Application options offered in API 14.